# what happens if i set the replication factor to 3 on a pseudo distributes mode cluster?

Tags: hadoop, replication

I tried changing the replication to 3 and I can see the replication is changed to 3 for the file I loaded into hdfs,but I cannot see the other 2 copies.Could someone answer what happens in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see any replica seen you don't have other node to create them. A replica can't be created in the same node. But in your NameNode you will see `Number of Under-Replicated Blocks` metric different to zero. If you attach a new data node in your cluster further, the **under-replicated** blocks should start the replication in automatic (obviously that imply to configure a full cluster instead the pseudo cluster).

You can see the `Number of Under-Replicated Blocks` metric in the Name node web ui: http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview (By default in a pseudo cluster configuration).

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to set the dfs.replication to "1", otherwise when running a single datanode or psuedodistributed mode, HDFS can't replicate blocks to the specified number of datanodes and it will warn about blocks being under-replicated